# How to link to dynamic pivot table with Prisma/MySQL

Tags: mysql, graphql, prisma

I have this structure in MySQL:

| person |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | name |  |

| phone |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | number |

| tag |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | slug |

| tag_map |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | reference_table | reference_id | tag_id |

And in GraphQL SDL like:

```
type Person {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  tags: [Tag]
  phones: [Phone]
}
type Phone {
  id: ID!
  number: String
  tags: [Tag]
  forPerson: Person!
}
# more types, queries, mutation, and inputs
```

I have made the resolvers which resolve out to the tags, but trying to write filters that work somewhat natively with prisma to filter phones or people that have associated tags is troublesome to get going. Mainly because there is no native Prisma link between the person and the tag or the phone and the tag.

I understand there is no native Prisma link because in the `tag_map` pivot table, the `reference_id` is not a foreign key relationship by itself, but rather only when combined with the `reference_table`.

So while this works to allow one set of tags for all types, and only requires one pivot table for the many to many relationships, this fails with filtering.

**Is there anyway to link the tag model in Prisma to the phone and person models?**

My Prisma schema setup looks something like:

```
model person {
  id     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name   String    @db.VarChar(45)
  phones phone[]

  // tags   tag[]  <-- How to link this with Prisma

}
model phone {
  id     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  number String    @db.VarChar(25)
  person person?   @relation(fields: [forPerson], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "phone_person")

  // tags   tag[]  <-- How to link this with Prisma

  @@index([forPerson], map: "phone_person_idx")
}
model tag {
  id     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug   String?   @unique(map: "tag_UNIQUE") @db.VarChar(15)
  tagmap tagmap[]
}
model tagmap {
  id               Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  reference_table  String    @db.VarChar(15)
  reference_id     Int       @db.UnsignedInt
  tag_id           Int       @db.UnsignedInt
  tag              tag       @relation(fields: [tag_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "tag")

  @@unique([reference, reference_id, tag_id], map: "index1")
  @@index([reference], map: "index2")
  @@index([reference_id], map: "index3")
  @@index([tag_id], map: "index4")
}

// more models
```

Comment: for time being, I'll just not worry about db schema and just use the implicit pivot table feature from prisma. Not that big of a deal I guess for now, but would be nice to be able to do relationships one sided only without needing foreign keys

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of the `tag_map` table and create two different relations between `tag`- `person` and `tag`-`phone`? Prisma would create the underlying pivot table for these relations. Would this have any issue, besides an additional join table (that Prisma creates internally)?

Comment: @TasinIshmam In actual code I have many more tables and was trying to stop from having a ton of pivot tables just for relationships. This dynamic pivot table fixes the schema problem in the db, but makes it unusable in prism without custom coding EVERYTHING. In the end, I was hoping to have a single pivot table that was capable of connecting any two rows from any two tables, but that is not looking promising.

Comment: I see!  Unfortunately, Prisma doesn't really support this at the moment. Would you kindly consider [creating a feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) for this? It would really help us understand the demand for this feature and inform our decision on feature development.

Comment: @TasinIshmam I created: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11098 maybe others from the community can review this and provide feedback/value on it.

Comment: This is super detailed and helpful. Thank you!